PostgreSQL Export from Adminer Results in "zero-length delimited identifier" Error
I've been experiencing an issue with PostgreSQL after exporting my database using Adminer. The exported SQL file seems to have some problems that cause errors when I try to import it into another PostgreSQL database.
The error message I'm getting is:
Error in query: ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...ents_lock_createdAt" ON "public"."patients" USING btree ("")

This error seems to be caused by an empty string "" being used as a column name in a CREATE INDEX statement, which is not valid in PostgreSQL.
Additionally, I'm encountering another error:
Error in query: ERROR: function on_accounting_items_updated() does not exist

This error is due to the PostgreSQL database being unable to find the function on_accounting_items_updated().
I've checked the export settings in Adminer and they seem to be correct. I've also tried manually inspecting the exported SQL file for any obvious issues, but couldn't find any.
Here how i exported it. But dont know why when i import the same file after drop db and use it , i encounter many errors also these ones. Why i can not run the sql command that exported before, and run into many errors?


Here also the lines that fire error also
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "accountingItems";
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS "accountingItems_id_seq";
CREATE SEQUENCE "accountingItems_id_seq" INCREMENT  MINVALUE  MAXVALUE  CACHE ;

